# Fake a subdomain in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am currently working on a web app that will be running in an iframe on the webpages of our customers. Now i would like to setup google analytics tracking in a way that i that i can easily distinguish one customer from the other. My plan is to "fake" subdomains, even though it is always the same TLD, so that i can setup a profile for each customer, but still have overall analytics as well.

For example my URL is http://www.domain.com/#/3 where 3 is the customer id. Now i would like to see that in google analytics as 3.domain.com.
Is that possible by doing something like this:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-1', 'domain.com');
ga('set', 'location', 'http://id.domain.com');
```

or do i have to go about this in another way? My google analytics knowledge is limited to reading the stats and tracking events and pageviews, so maybe there is a whole different and better way to do this - i am open for suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be much better to use [custom variables](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables) for this purpose. They give you additional segmentation possibilities on any values and metrics you need, such as customer names or IDs (or both ...)

Comment: Thanks, i will try it with those variables!